# using a variable to specify a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to access a column in a data frame using a variable , this variable wil be populated
in a loop

```
atr<-"yield_kgha"
```

so what i want is the second line below where `$atr` to act like it was `$yield_kgha`

I tried `$get(atr)` with no luck ... how do I get atr to be taken literally

```
meanis=MEAN = mean(zones[[zonename]]$yield_kgha , na.rm = TRUE) #get the mean yield_kgha in the zone
meanis=MEAN = mean(zones[[zonename]]$atr , na.rm = TRUE) #get the mean yield_kgha in the zone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use an object, then use `[[` instead of `$` similar to the 'zonename'

```
mean(zones[[zonename]][[atr]] , na.rm = TRUE) #
```